# I deleted the auto generated pages on my asp.net web app and messed with site.master. Now bootstrap theme won't work

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, bootswatch

So on my asp.net web app project, I deleted the default/about/contact auto generated pages and changed the site.master to redirect the home/login/registration links on the nav bar to my own pages. I also right clicked on my own home web form and 'set as start page'.

After doing all of this, I then tried to add a bootswatch theme, and even though it shows the navigation bar in the new themes colour when viewing designer mode, when I run the app, it is all in the default theme. Does anyone know why this is happening? I'll paste my site.master code, if that helps? Thanks in advance!

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs"Inherits="Coursework.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title><%: Page.Title %> - My ASP.NET Application</title>

<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
<link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/Home.aspx">Learn-on-Line</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Home.aspx">Home</a></li>                        
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Registration.aspx">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> !</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sounds like your old page is still in the chase. press  shift + F5  in browser or rebuild the solution. :)

Comment: It didn't work :( thanks though